# How to scroll to top, without making the page to refresh?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm making a page, containing a form, and I'm trying to make it scroll back to the top, everything I'm trying refreshes the page. Any idea to avoid this?

Here's the code of the script:

```
function vizsgalja_h_ki_van_toltve()
{
    var csaladnev=document.getElementById("csaladnev").value;
    var keresztnev=document.getElementById("keresztnev").value;
    var CNP=document.getElementById("CNP").value;

    var magyar;
    for(var i=0; i<document.getElementsByName("magyar").length; ++i)
            if(document.getElementsByName("magyar")[i].checked) 
                    magyar=document.getElementsByName("magyar")[i].value;

    var roman;
    for(var i=0; i<document.getElementsByName("roman").length; ++i)
            if(document.getElementsByName("roman")[i].checked) 
                    roman=document.getElementsByName("roman")[i].value;                 

    var angol;
    for(var i=0; i<document.getElementsByName("angol").length; ++i)
            if(document.getElementsByName("angol")[i].checked) 
                    angol=document.getElementsByName("angol")[i].value;

    var tortenelem;
    for(var i=0; i<document.getElementsByName("tortenelem").length; ++i)
            if(document.getElementsByName("tortenelem")[i].checked) 
                    tortenelem=document.getElementsByName("tortenelem")[i].value;

    var irasbeli="";
    for(var i=0; i<document.getElementsByName("irasbeli").length; ++i)
            if(document.getElementsByName("irasbeli")[i].checked) 
                    irasbeli=irasbeli+document.getElementsByName("irasbeli")[i].value+"<br>";

    for(var i=0; i<document.getElementsByName("irasbeli2").length; ++i)
            if(document.getElementsByName("irasbeli2")[i].checked) 
                    irasbeli=irasbeli+document.getElementsByName("irasbeli2")[i].value+"<br>";


    if(!csaladnev || !keresztnev || !CNP)
    {
        document.body.scrollTop = document.documentElement.scrollTop = 0;
        document.getElementById("msg").innerHTML="Nincs minden adat kitöltve. Kérelek add meg ezeket.";// I want to make the page scroll to the top when this message appears.

    }

    else
    {
        document.getElementById("msg").innerHTML="";
        document.getElementById("form").innerHTML="<h3>A megadott adataid:</h3>Családnév: :"+csaladnev+"<br>Keresztnev: "+keresztnev+"<br>C.N.P: "+CNP+"<br><br><h3>Szóbelik:</h3>Magyar: "+magyar+"<br>Román: "+roman+"<br>Angol:"+angol+"<br>Történelem"+tortenelem+"<br><h3>Írásbelik:</h3>"+irasbeli;
    }

}
```

This is the only function, which loads after a click on a button on the page. I want to make the page get to the top, if that message appears (I've put a comment there in the code).

Edit: Maybe if I make an anchor on the top, but how do I go there from the script?

Comment: Try `if(document.getElementById("msg")) { window.scrollTo(0,0); }`

Answer (score 0):

Add this to the `head` of your code :

```
<div id="top" style="display:none;"></div>
```

And use this in your javascript:

```
window.location = "#top";
```

It should work, if no error.

You should be able to see the effect with this snippet :

```
<div id="top"></div><div style="display:block;height:100%;width:100%;background-color:#000000;"><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br></div><a href="#" onclick='window.location="#top";'>top</a>
```

Comment: An example is added. Why not check it out? Tell me after you checked it. I will delete it afterwards and post the code here :)

Comment: Why a `div` and not an anchor? `<a id="top"></a>` They're supposed to be used in these cases: http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/links.html#h-12.2.3

Comment: What's the matter? It will not affect it at all! Also, remember to put it right after `<head>`, to prevent other seen elements before it.

Comment: Also, @user3578184, are you still waiting for the 10 minutes limit to choose my answer to be correct?

Comment: The div appears and then disappears. Remains visible only for the second, third click on the button. And I checked the example.

Comment: I don't really understand. What do you mean?

Comment: I have edited the code. It should work very well without any problem. Added `style="display:none;"`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this may be it helps

```
window.onload = function() { setTimeout (function () {  scrollTo(0,0); }, 0);}
```